# How to write a Dictionary to Excel in Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, dictionary

I have the following dictionary in python that represents a From - To Distance Matrix.

```
graph = {'A':{'A':0,'B':6,'C':INF,'D':6,'E':7},

         'B':{'A':INF,'B':0,'C':5,'D':INF,'E':INF},

         'C':{'A':INF,'B':INF,'C':0,'D':9,'E':3},

         'D':{'A':INF,'B':INF,'C':9,'D':0,'E':7},

         'E':{'A':INF,'B':4,'C':INF,'D':INF,'E':0}

         }
```

Is it possible to output this matrix into excel or to a csv file so that it has the following format? I have looked into using csv.writer and csv.DictWriter but can not produce the desired output.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may create a pandas dataframe from that dict, then save to CSV or Excel:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(graph).T  # transpose to look just like the sheet above
df.to_csv('file.csv')
df.to_excel('file.xls')
```

Comment: Works perfectly Thank you! Let me take this one step further. Would it be possible, given a set of dataframe pairs, to sum their corresponding values from the dataframe? For example, if I had the pairs (A,E), (A,F), and (B,D) I would want to return the sum of their values (6+7+5) = 18

Comment: Sure, with a given list of pairs, i.e.: `pairs = [('A', 'E'), ('A', 'F'), ('B', 'D')]` you can do `sum(df.ix[pair] for pair in pairs)`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most minimal result, but pandas would solve this marvellously (and if you're doing data analysis of any kind, I can highly recommend pandas!).

Your data is already in a perfectformat for bringing into a Dataframe

```
INF = 'INF'
graph = {'A':{'A':0,'B':6,'C':INF,'D':6,'E':7},

         'B':{'A':INF,'B':0,'C':5,'D':INF,'E':INF},

         'C':{'A':INF,'B':INF,'C':0,'D':9,'E':3},

         'D':{'A':INF,'B':INF,'C':9,'D':0,'E':7},

         'E':{'A':INF,'B':4,'C':INF,'D':INF,'E':0}
         }
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(graph).to_csv('OUTPUT.csv')
```

[image: Contents of OUTPUT.csv]
but the output you want is this Transposed, so:

```
pd.DataFrame(graph).T.to_csv('OUTPUT.csv')
```

where T returns the transpose of the Dataframe.